# Boot from NFS drive with persistence

Tags: boot, nfs, pxe, nas, persistence

I have installed PXELinux on my Synology NAS and unpacked the ubuntu ISO in the NAS.
I can now boot from my PC thru PXE into ubuntu.
This is how my pxelinux entry looks:

```
LABEL Ubuntu
Menu label Ubuntu 
kernel images/ubuntu/casper/vmlinuz.efi
append boot=casper vga=normal locale=de_de netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.178.33:/volume1/TFTP/boot/images/ubuntu initrd=images/ubuntu/casper/initrd.lz persistent
```

But I don't know where to put the casper-rw filesystem?
Also I would like to have a home directory on the NAS.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the casper scripts I found that the system takes a casper-rw file only if it is on a vfat device.

If I want to use nfs, a device with the label "casper-rw" must be there, not a file.