# PXE Boot into Ubuntu Live + Persistence (casper-rw): Possible? Limitations?

Tags: boot, nfs, pxe, persistence

I have setup a PXE Boot Server on the network (Not Ubuntu, but NethServer for anyone interested), and have gotten Ubuntu 16.04 booting properly from this server.

Here is the `pxelinux.cfg/default` entry for it:

```
label 1
menu label ^1) Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1 x64 Live
  kernel ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64/casper/vmlinuz.efi
  append rootfstype=nfs4 boot=casper persistent netboot=nfs nfsroot=10.1.1.1:/home/tftpdata/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64 initrd=ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64/casper/initrd.lz --
```

I probably don't need the `rootfstype=nfs4`, but it works, so I'll leave it for now.

My question relates to the `persistent` option.

From what limited information I can find that relates to 16.04, if I want the client to have any kind of persistence, it has to have a `casper-rw` setup, but I can't figure out how to serve this over NFS at boot.

There doesn't seem to be any switch or path.

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/577804/606721), which seems to allude to the idea that I might need a partition or some such, named `casper-rw`?  There aren't many more details I can find.

I do know that `casper-rw` can be a loop file, I know it can also be a partition.  But is it possible to serve this over NFS at the time of boot to the PXE client?

Every other reference seems to be related to 14.04 or earlier, and the majority seem to be for 9.10 and lower.

The end goal is to have a PXE Boot diskless workstation, that I can install drivers and applications on.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/577637/boot-from-nfs-drive-with-persistence?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yup, I already posted that in the question, but unfortunately, it doesn't contain a lot of information.  It makes me think it's possible, I just don't know how.  :)

Comment: Thinking outside the box, could you loop mount a vfat partition as decribed [here?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-mount-as-loop-an-image-of-a-vfat-made-with-dd-791142/). I don't have the setup available for testing....

Comment: I'd thought of that.  Great idea, but how to serve it over NFS via PXE...  It's had me at a loss for almost a month now.  Haha!

Comment: I would think that this could be done by mounting nfsroot as the root filesystem and modifying /nfsroot/etc/fstab to loopmount a diskimage stored in nfsroot that has the modifications you desire. Some of this is outlined [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto) I hesitate to write an answer as I don't have the gear configured to test it.

Comment: Do you really need the files that will be saved? If yes... why using the Casper not "normal" NFS way ?!? If you do not need them - ramdisk /tmpfs.

Comment: From what I understand, using an NFS mount for files would be fine, except you couldn't upgrade the live image to support newer drivers and packages, without rebuilding the whole image. If I understand the Casper-RW, it's mounted during boot, and can contain drivers and packages installed during the last usage of the image.  So I'm thinking of it like a diskless workstation.

Comment: ThatGuy,  @RostislavKandilarov meant that you copy/extract the root file system into the NFS shared folder (not the live image), as explained in the link mentioned previously by  ElderGeek , https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto , see section: *Creating your NFS installation*

Answer (score 3):

[I would have preferred to leave this as a comment but I don't have the rep.]

I've been down this road trying to implement what I consider hybrid thin / diskless clients with PXE at the core. Originally I researched and tried NFS and used various ways to persist data. In the end, I found the method that was most resilient (as well as manageable) was to use PXE to iSCSI. By no means a trivial undertaking but once deployed it works quite well and affords all those standard management practices one desires. The primary difference is with iSCSI you have to largely preallocate a disk size.

The "how-to" is infrastructure dependent so I'll cite a reference:
http://backreference.org/2013/12/23/diskless-iscsi-boot-with-pxe-howto/

(this is not a *"your answer is somewhere in here"* post)

Comment: Thanks. I have a NAS that supports iSCSI, so I'll look into it :)

Comment: If Synology they have a ton of docs (and if not the NAS Qnap etc is probably very similar): https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/search/iscsi?p_type=all&p=1

Comment: Cheers. It's a Thecus N7700. Hopefully, I can translate into Thecusese. They aren't well known for user friendly setup. :)

Comment: Here's some official Ubuntu iSCSI reference for the client: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html#iscsi

Comment: I'm still working on it, and I cant accept it as an answer, but you deserve something for your work, it was indeed helpful.  I awarded you the bounty, and an upvote.  I hope that's ok.  I'll offer more of a bounty in the future. :)

Comment: Quite kind of you, thank you. I've found what you can do with pxe invaluable, especially using iPXE (ipxe.org). Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

As I was not sure whether to ask this as a separate question or not here I am shamelessly plugging in my question. Sorry in Advance
So here is an idea 'How about instead of trying to add a `casper-rw` file how about we add a persistence like in Kali Linux. So like when it boots off the network and there will be a command to look for a particular named drive which can then be configured for every system to have one with different settings just like Kali Persistence. Please share your thoughts on whether it might be possible and also if not. Thanks in advance